# Failed to install Ipthw.web

Tags: python

I tried to install `Ipthw.web` by

```
sudo pip install Ipthw.web
```

But I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Ipthw.web (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Ipthw.web
```

How do I install it?

Comment: Is it possible that you want [Lpth.web](https://pypi.org/project/lpthw.web/)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade your pip version with this:

```sh
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then retry, I think you made a grammatical mistake

```sh
sudo pip install lpthw.web
```

Comment: Try: python -m pip install --upgrade pip got:No module named pip